# How Improve Run-time when sorting arrays

Tags: java, arrays, compare

I have managed to create a working solution for "Mixing Milk" for USACO, but the judge says my program takes too long.

I think this has to do with the way I sort the list of Farmers by asking price in lines 29 - 44. Is there any way I can improve the run time?

```
/*
 ID:
 LANG: JAVA
 TASK: milk
 */
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class milk {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("test.in"))));
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new File("test.out"));
//        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("milk.in"))));
//        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new File("milk.out"));
        String[] st = s.readLine().split(" ");
        int N = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
        int M = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
        int[] P = new int[M];
        int[] A = new int[M];
        String[] sets = new String[M];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            sets[i] = s.readLine();
            st = sets[i].split(" ");
            P[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
        }
        int maxp = ("" + maxVal(P)).length();
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            st = sets[i].split(" ");
            while (st[0].length() < maxp) {
                st[0] = "0" + st[0];
            }
            sets[i] = st[0] + " " + st[1];
        }
        Arrays.sort(sets);
        int cap = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < M && cap <= N; i++) {
            st = sets[i].split(" ");
            P[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[0]);
            A[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[1]);
            cap += A[i];
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int units = 0;
        int a;
        for (int i = 0; units < N; i++) {
            if (A[i] <= N - units) {
                sum = sum + P[i] * A[i];
                units += A[i];
            } else {
                a = N - units;
                if (a > A[i]) {
                    a = A[i];
                }
                sum = sum + P[i] * a;
                units += a;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(units);
        System.out.println(sum);
        w.println(sum);
        w.close();
        double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Took " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds.");
    }

    public static int maxVal(int[] x) {
        int max = 0;
        for (int i : x) {
            if (i > max) {
                max = i;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Thanks Andreas!

Changed code and made the time limit:

```
/*
 ID:
 LANG: JAVA
 TASK: milk
 */

import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class milk {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        double startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
//        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("test.in"))));
//        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new File("test.out"));
        BufferedReader s = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("milk.in"))));
        PrintWriter w = new PrintWriter(new File("milk.out"));
        String temp = s.readLine();
        int spc = temp.indexOf(" ");
        int N = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, spc));
        int M = Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(spc + 1));
        System.out.println(N + " " + M);
        int[] P = new int[M];
        int[] A = new int[M];
        Farmer[] f = new Farmer[M];
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            temp = s.readLine();
            spc = temp.indexOf(" ");
            f[i] = new Farmer(Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(0, spc)), Integer.parseInt(temp.substring(spc + 1)));
        }
        Arrays.sort(f);
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            P[i] = f[i].getPrice();
            A[i] = f[i].getInventory();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        int units = 0;
        int a;
        for (int i = 0; units < N; i++) {
            if (A[i] <= N - units) {
                sum = sum + P[i] * A[i];
                units += A[i];
            } else {
                a = N - units;
                if (a > A[i]) {
                    a = A[i];
                }
                sum = sum + P[i] * a;
                units += a;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(units);
        System.out.println(sum);
        w.println(sum);
        w.close();
        double endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Took " + ((endTime - startTime) / 1000) + " seconds.");
    }
}

class Farmer implements Comparable<Farmer> {

    private int price;
    private int inventory;

    public Farmer(int price, int inventory) {
        this.price = price;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getInventory() {
        return inventory;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Farmer f1) {
        if (f1.price != this.price) {
            return this.price - f1.price;
        } else if (f1.inventory != this.inventory) {
            return f1.inventory - this.inventory;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow readers are not going to count lines in your post.  Please add something to indicate which lines are 29 and 44.

Comment: line 29: int maxp = ("" + maxVal(P)).length();
.
.
.
line 44: cap += A[i];

Comment: What is `st[1]`?  Off the top of my head, sorting integers by converting them to strings and padding leading 0's doesn't seem like an efficient way to do things.  Keeping the integers as integers and doing integer comparisons would seem to work better.  If you really need to sort on two keys, and `st[1]` is a text field, you can create a class with two fields and define a comparator that will compare the integer field and compare the second field if the integer fields are equal.  I don't know for sure whether that will be much faster, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: Other areas of improvement: You're splitting each string twice (why not save the result?).  You're using `parseInt` on the first field in that string twice.  If you must do a zero pad, repeatedly prepending `"0"` is a slow way to do it.  Instead, compute the number of 0's you need first.  One way to create a string with that many 0's is to use a substring of `"000000000000"`.  I still don't think you should need to do this.

Comment: @Sarutobi0997 Post your code here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that might help.

Comment: @ajb FYI: After the `sort()`, OP also does a `parseInt(st[1])`, so lines are two integers separated by a single space. In total, `split()` is called 3 times per line.

Comment: @Andreas yup, I noticed that later.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is an Object-Oriented language. Use it.

Your code keeps processing String lines, splitting and concatenating. That is slow.

Read your lines into objects containing the two integer values. Make the class implement `Comparable`, to sort by the two values, so you can call `sort()`.

The processing is faster because you only parse the numbers once. The sorting is faster because you don't have to zero-pad the numbers, and you sort by integers, not string.

Since your lines consist of two integers separated by a single space, don't use `split()`. Use `indexOf(' ')` and call `substring()` twice. It's faster and less memory intensive.